# How to add can i add comment form with queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**Info**: i have sales_item QuerySet in view. i want to approve, decline and add some comments on specific sales_items. i also include html code were add sales list and form is inside of a dropdown menu. Where the menu pops up and we fill out the form.

**Problem**: The code below of views file is getting error `Sale matching query does not exist.`

**models.py**

```
class Authorize(models.Model):
    APPROVED = 'AP'
    DECLINED = 'DL'
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
        (DECLINED, 'Declined'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sales_item = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=APPROVED, max_length=2)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AuthorizeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Authorize
        fields = [
            'comments',
            'status'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def SalesListView(request):
    queryset = Sale.objects.all()
    auth_form = AuthorizeForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        sales = Sale.objects.get(id=pk)

        if auth_form.is_valid():
            approved = auth_form.save(commit=False)
            approved.sales_item = sales
            approved.save()

    context = {
        'sales': queryset,
        'form': auth_form
    }
    return render(request, 'pending_sale.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for object in sales %}
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="hpanel hblue">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h4><a href="#"> {{ object.customers }}</a></h4>
                    <p>
                        {{ object.content }}
                    </p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="project-label">Saler</div>
                            <small>{{ object.saler }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="project-label">Timestamp</div>
                            <small>{{ object.created_on|naturalday }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="project-label">Product</div>
                            <small>{{ object.created_on|naturalday }}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 project-info">
                    <div class="project-action">
                        <div class="dropdown">

                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default"> View</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Edit
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu auth-form-dropdown dropdown-menu-sw " style="width:352px;">
                                    <a class="Link">
                                        <i class="pe-7s-help1" style="font-style: 150px;"></i>
                                    </a>

                                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                                        Approvels
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        <form action="." method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <textarea name="comments" id="id_comments" cols="30" rows="2" required
                                                    class="form-control" placeholder="comments..."></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" float-right">
                                                <div id="id_status">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="status" value="AP" required
                                                        id="id_status_0">
                                                    <label for="id_status_0" class="waves-effect waves-themed"
                                                        required>Approved</label>

                                                    <input type="radio" name="status" value="DL" required
                                                        id="id_status_1">
                                                    <label for="id_status_1" class="waves-effect waves-themed"
                                                        required>Declined</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                                                style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px; font-weight: 400;">submit</button>
                                        </form>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="project-value">
                        <h2 class="text-info">
                            ${{ object.products.price }}
                        </h2>
                        <p id="stores"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you include the form and/or the template that you submit when making a post request to SalesListView please

Comment: do you have any field name called  "pk" in your template ?? if yes then check that pk is not valid. it says there is no Sale with the PK value.

Comment: @ShaidHasanShawon no Dear there is no field called "pk" in my template

Comment: @Danoram Yes please Dear take a look my Question is updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get his exception while trying to get object by:

sales = Sale.objects.get(id=pk)

You can catch this error by this example

```
try:
    sales = Sale.objects.get(id=pk)
except Sale.DoesNotExist:
    return ValidationError(f'No sale by id {pk}')
```

Try to check, what primary key you passed into query, does it exists in database, and return error if not.
Maybe you nees to create Sale if it doesn't exist

Comment: yes this code is getting `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'get'` what should i do?

Comment: if this param is required and user didn't set it on front-end, just return error to user 
you could read more about it [django-artice-form-validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/)

Answer (score 1):

The primary key('pk') you are passing is not valid.Try fetching some id i.e primary key using a simple print statement

```
q=Sale.objects.all().values('id')
print(q)
```

Try these two commands to know what are the available id options you have and then try working on the queryset.

Anyways there is another ways to do this task instead of using a form you can pass the id directly into the url section .[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcJegVlKqqs) is a nice tutorial explaining how to pass id through url.